# Get numeric value of cat output

Tags: text-processing, variable, numeric-data

When I save result of cat to the variable I get the following:

```
wfpd=$'16213\r'
```

How can I convert this result to numeric value in order to use it as an argument to another command

Answer (score 3):

You can use parameter expansion to remove the trailing `\r`. `%` means "remove from the end of the value".

```
wfpd=$'16213\r'
wfpd=${wfpd%$'\r'}
((wfpd == 16213)) || echo Wrong
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *know* there's a character at the end of the value of `$wfpd` that you need to delete, and if you're using `bash` or `zsh` or  busybox `sh`¹, then you may do

```
wfpd="${wfpd:0:-1}"
```

This would remove the last character from the value of the variable, regardless of what it is.  It is a substring expansion specific to the mentioned shells that expands to the value of the character from offset zero to the last character in the string minus one.

---

<sup>¹  1.28.0 or newer, and if built with `ENABLE_HUSH_BASH_COMPAT` for `hush`, `ENABLE_ASH_BASH_COMPAT` for `ash` (default)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, `${var:offset:length}` is from ksh93, but IIRC negative lengths is from bash, works in zsh, but not ksh93. zsh and yash have `${wfpd[1,-2]}`

Comment: `${wfpd:0:${#wfpd}-1}` would work in ksh93 and mksh, and with `${wfpd:0:$((${#wfpd}-1))}` it would also work with older versions of busybox  sh.

Answer (score 1):

With `ksh93`, `zsh` or `bash`, you can use:

```
wfpd=${wfpd//[^[:digit:]-]}
```

To remove all the characters other than 0123456789- from the content of `$wfpd` (assuming decimal integers, you'd need to adapt for floating points or hexadecimal...).

POSIXly, you can use:

```
wfpd=${wfpd%%[![:digit:]-]*}
```

to remove the portion of `$wfpd` starting with the first character other than 0123456789- or:

```
wfpd=${wfpd%"${wfpd##*[[:digit:]]}"}
```

to remove everything after the last decimal digit.

Instead of doing:

```
wfpd=$(cat < file)
```

You  could also do:

```
IFS=$'\r' read wfpd rest_ignored < file
```

Which would read the first line of the file up to the first `\r` into `$wfpd` without even spawning a new process or executing a command.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively remove all except digits from the variable name. If the variable name is saved in a file called `file.txt`, then:

```
cat file.txt 
wfpd=$'16213\r'

cat file.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
16213
```